# symfony2 doctrine2: addselect elements to existing entity

Tags: performance, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine2.

There are many instances when I have an entity and I need to loop through its associated entities. Of course it often triggers new queries and is not very performant.

Would there be a best practice to `addselect` other entities to an existing one?

Think about when you use a paramconverter in symfony. It just gets you the entity. What if I retrieve an order and want to loop through its `orderLines`? Do I need to build a new query and `retrieve->leftjoin('order.orderlines', 'l')->addselect('l')->where('order = $order')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice in this case is to use a custom repository method that explicitly joins the associated entity.  Then Doctrine will not have to query individually through every iteration of the loop.  You can also use this [custom repository method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter) in the ParamConverter.

### Custom Repository Method:

Here's an example Controller:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/blog/{id}")
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="MyBundle:Order", 
    options={"repository_method" = "findOrderWithLineItems"})
 */
public function showAction(Order $order)
{
}
```

Then specifying the custom repository on the entity:

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\OrderRepository")
 */
class Order
{
}
```

Then your custom repository:

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class OrderRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOrderWithLineItems($id)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->join('o.orderLines', 'ol')
            ->where('o.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

### Always Join via Eager Fetching:

If instead you want to *always* fetch the associated entity (always join the table), even when doing a simple select on the base entity, you can specify an eager join on the associated entity:

```
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderLines", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $orderLines;
}
```

Comment: nice, I forgot about that for paramconverters! and outside that case, when you for instance get entities from an entity select field? or from anywhere else and where you couldn't change how you got it?

Comment: You can also explicitly set `fetch="EAGER"` on the association in the entity to automatically fetch it at all times.  I'll add an example for that too

Comment: and so would you confirm that in other cases there is no other solution than calling a custom query to fetch other entity attributes?

Comment: No like I posted, you can put an eager fetch on the associated column and it will always join. So if you do that and then do a `find()` on your Order entity, it will join order line items automatically